# On Android, how to read the exact text of a file, when one finishes with a newline, and another doesn't

Tags: android, json, string, unity-game-engine, newline

This is related to a situation I find myself in working with saving text files in Unity on Android, then reading them in native Android.

One of the files we read is a HMACMD5 signature, created with the code,

```
byte[] bData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (data);
byte[] bKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (key);
using (HMACMD5 hmac = new HMACMD5(bKey)) {
    byte[] signature = hmac.ComputeHash (bData);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String (signature);
}
```

And then written to the phone with,

```
public static void SaveText (string path, string data) {
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)) {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs)) {
          sw.Write (data);
        }
    }
}
```

The other string we're saving is a JSON string dump.  The signature has a newline character at the end of the string, but the JSON string doesn't.  I know I can manually add one, but this question is about reading the accurate file contents.

On Android, based on previous SO answers, I read the file with,

```
String readFile(File file) {
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append("\n");
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        MyLogger.e(LOG_TAG, "Error opening file " + file.getPath(), e);
    }

    return text.toString();
}
```

I'm manually adding the newline character after every line, but if I do this, I don't accurately read the JSON file, which doesn't have a newline character at the end.  If I *don't* add the newline, I don't accurately read the signature file, which does.

Answer (score 0):

You better then do not use readLine() but read().